# Look for changes in display block/none and animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I'm looking for a way to listen to all changes in display block/none and animate them in JQuery/JavaScript.

The switch from display to block is being made by VUE.JS

I searched in several places but i could not find what i was looking for. Is this possible?

```
&.contacts {
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
     header#home {
        display: none;
     }
     header#projects {
        display: none;
     }
     header#services {
        display: none;
     }
     header#contacts {
        display: block;
        transition: $transition;
     }
  }
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/nunoooo/pen/XKodQm?editors=1100

Thank you

Comment: The CSS `display` property is not animatable.

Comment: I know that applies to CSS but i did not know that jquery could not animate it, dam.. Thank you !

Comment: Well, it kinda is animatable iwth js, but has some non pleasant side effects.Just use juerys fadeTo method, or show() and hide() set the display to none.Or just use css classes with a transition specified.

Comment: @damiano celent Yes that works with css or with js, but the unpleasant side effect it's worse than i intended :(  that is why i was wondering if there was another way, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because we can't apply transition for display property, so please try to do as below with opacity. To be honest your code is very messy and you should refactor it again.

1. Style header with

> ```
> header {
>   opacity: 0; 
>   transition: $transition; 
> }
> ```

2. Then do like so

> ```
> &.contacts {
>      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
>      header#home, header#projects, header#services {
>         opacity: 0;
>      }
>      header#contacts {
>         opacity: 1;        
>      }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm trying to do a single page website with vue and css, and opacity does the trick, but the positioning of elements switching from page to page, gets broken obviously, only the display property works as intended, unfortunately.

Comment: I see, let me think about this context.